# java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.NoSuchFileException: File not found: /tmp/hive/

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have following code :

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Fleet")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
  .set("spark.cores.max", "12")
  .set("spark.driver.cores", "4")
  .set("spark.ui.port", "4040")
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
  .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "30")

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Fleet")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.40")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
  .config("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val topics = Map("historyfleet" -> 1) 
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "192.168.0.40:2181", "fleetgroup", topics)

kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  {
    val dfs = rdd.toDF()
    println(dfs.show())
    dfs.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("table" -> "test", "keyspace" -> "test_db")).mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
  })
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

}

I can execute this program from Eclipse on local machine but when trying to execute through spark submit job on cluster , it gives an error as :-

```
ERROR 2018-05-21 13:00:27,009 org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper: Failed to start or submit Spark application
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.NoSuchFileException: File not found: /tmp/hive/
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:189) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.16.jar:2.0.2.16]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.16.jar:2.0.2.16]
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.16.jar:2.0.2.16]
```

My idea is to fetch records from Kafka stream and push the data into Cassandra. Thanks,

Comment: are you running in a windows cluster? Also get rid of `master("local[*]")` but I believe that has nothing to do with the error

Comment: No its a Linux cluster. and Whenever I deploy my application on cluster, always comment - master("local[*]") this. to make sure that it should be deployed on cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase replication factor (rf) for `dsefs` keyspace to a value bigger than one. Also, `dsefs` keyspace (as any other keyspace) works best with `NetworkTopologyStrategy`. Here is a command that changes the strategy with rf = 3.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE dsefs WITH replication = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', '<YOUR DC HERE>': '3'}
```

After altering keyspace you need to run node repair an **all** nodes.

```
nodetool repair dsefs
```

Alternatively to all this you could remove `/tmp/hive` from DSEFS and recreate it with

```
dse fs
mkdir -p -m 733 /tmp/hive
```

Comment: are you sure about this ? dsefs is file system keyspace. I may loose my entire cluster

Comment: NetworkTopologyStrategy is what DSEFS docs recommend
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/analytics/configUsingDsefs.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try this solution with dummy cluster . Right now my issue got resolved. I was starting Cassandra in normal mode. I had to start with -k to enable Analytic mode.